# Ansible: Fetch a dynamic list of files from HTTP server

Tags: ansible

I have a bunch of files on a Nexus server and I can browse the raw repo using the REST service with a web browser.

The zip files that reside on the site are not static and could have random names.

I have tried the `unarchive` and `get_url` modules, but they only work if I know the remote filename.

The only option I have now is to use the `command` module and download the files with curl or wget.

```
wget -r -np -l 1 -A zip \ 
http://localhost:8081/service/rest/repository/browse/repo/installs/latest/
```

Is there a better way of achieving this with an Ansible module?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a better way of achieving this with an Ansible module?

```
- uri:
    url: http://localhost:8081/service/rest/repository/browse/repo/installs/latest/
    return_content: yes
  register: the_files
- debug: var=the_zips
  vars:
    the_zips: >-
     {{ the_files.content | regex_findall("\w+\.zip") }}
```

would be my guess, but it really depends on exactly how "random" we are talking about with those filenames.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you!

The filename gets duplicated (from the html text and the href tag) but easily modifiable with the regex. Thanks again.